# How can I get form data without page reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically, I am making a browser dashboard that will transmit the data submitted to a discord webhook. So far I was able to get the form to stop refreshing because I want a message to pop up at the bottom when they submit the data correctly. This is what I tried so far. I haven't got to the discord set up yet. I want to see if I can gather the data from the form first then send it to webhook.

```
form = document.getElementById("submit-form");
sucessMsg = document.getElementById("success");


function sucess(event) {
sucessMsg.style.display = "inline"
event.preventDefault()

}


function getData() {
console.log(document.getElementById("teams").value)
}



form.addEventListener("submit" , sucess , getData)



    <form id="submit-form">
        <ol id="list_of_teams">
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
             <li id="teams"><input type="text"></li>
         </ol>
         <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit-btn">
    </form>
    <h2 id="success">successfully sent to discord</h2>
```

Comment: The attribute id should be unique in the page, and the property value is not valid for li element. Each input should have their own unique id in order to get its value with document.getElementById

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

```js
const form = document.getElementById("submit-form");
const sucessMsg = document.getElementById("success");

function sucess(event) {

  console.log("form data:", getData());

  sucessMsg.style.display = "inline"
  event.preventDefault();

}

function getData()
{
  const formData = new FormData(form),
        ret = {};

  for(let [name, value] of formData.entries())
    ret[name] = value;

  return ret;
}

form.addEventListener("submit", sucess)
```

```html
<form id="submit-form">
  <ol id="list_of_teams">
    <li class="teams"><input type="text" name="i1"></li>
    <li class="teams"><input type="text" name="i2"></li>
    <li class="teams"><input type="text" name="i3"></li>
    <li class="teams"><input type="text" name="i4"></li>
    <li class="teams"><input type="text" name="i5"></li>
  </ol>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit-btn">
</form>
<h2 id="success">successfully sent to discord</h2>
```

Just a few notes about your code:

1. element ID must be unique
2. third parameter in `addEventListener` is `bubbling` flag or options, not a callback
3. form can only submit data from elements that have `name` attribute assigned to them, so in your example the form will not submit anything.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. I was able to retrieve the data with those changes thank you much I still have a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may help to void a page refresh.

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" id="submit-form">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that:

```js
const sForm = document.querySelector('#submit-form')

sForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault() // disable submit 

  let inputJSON =
    Array
    .from(new FormData(sForm))
    .reduce( (r, [name,value]) =>
      {
      if (name.endsWith('[]'))
        {
        name    = name.slice(0,-2)
        r[name] = r[name] ?? []
        r[name].push(value)
        }
      else r[name] = value; 
      return r
      } ,{})
  console.clear()
  console.log( inputJSON  )
  }
```

```html
<form id="submit-form">
  <ol >
    <li><input name="team[]" type="text"></li>
    <li><input name="team[]" type="text"></li>
    <li><input name="team[]" type="text"></li>
    <li><input name="team[]" type="text"></li>
   </ol>
   <button type="submit" >submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one out, seems like it should work

https://www.codexpedia.com/javascript/submitting-html-form-without-reload-the-page/

Comment: Link only answers are of little value on SO. Links should only be used to support what actually exists in the answer. If that link rots it will render the answer completely useless in the future

Comment: Thanks for the input, did not think about that one!